# How to distribute cores using mpirun

Tags: bash, mpi

I am trying to execute two processes at the same time on a VPS which has 16 cores and I'd like each job to utilize 8 cores each and max out the number of available cores.

So I thought that I could just execute two separate processes as such:

```bsh
$ mpirun -np 8 pmemd.MPI -O -i input_proc1.in -o output_proc1.out
$ mpirun -np 8 pmemd.MPI -O -i input_proc2.in -o output_proc2.out
```

In my mind this would put process 1 on cores 1-8 and process 2 on cores 9-16 though this was obviously not the case. Checking the `htop` output shows both these processes crowding over cores 1-8 leaving 8 cores not being utilised.

I am running these in the background buy placing a series of `mpirun` commands in a file in two separate folders and running each as such:

```bsh
$ nohup ./runscript.sh < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

To have them run in the background after I log out as each series of processes I need to run can take days to finish.

I figure you should be able to somehow "reserve" 8 cores (1-8) for one task and then when launching the next task which should then be forced to utilize the remaining 8 cores though I have yet managed to achieve the desired behavior using `--bind-to` options. I am not sure if this is related to the system being an OpenStack VPS machine or if I am just not doing it right.

I am using mpirun (Open MPI) 2.1.1 on a Ubuntu VPS running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

Any feedback or suggestions towards reaching the desired behavior would be gratefully appreciated

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after digging around quite a bit I found an answer to my problem on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47784610/how-to-use-mpirun-to-use-different-cpu-cores-for-different-programs). For my purposes I `apt-get` installed `hwloc` to map out the available cores using `lstopo -p` and then running my commands as:

```bsh
$ nohup mpirun --cpu-set 0-7 --bind-to core -np 8 pmemd.MPI [arguments]
$ nohup mpirun --cpu-set 8-15 --bind-to core -np 8 pmemd.MPI [arguments]
```

and this successfully distributed the first task over the first 8 cores and the second task over the remaining 8 cores utilizing all the available 16 cores fully.

I thought I'd post the answer here as well in case someone stumbles upon this question in the future.